# Arcade Coin Script for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hello!**

For a school project, I have to create a 2d Arcade Game. And one of the things that I have to include is a coin system. Let me explain:

In the main menu you start out with 3 coins, and whenever you click play, one coin will be spent so you will have 2 coins. At the end of some levels, you can pick a coin up so it will refill in the main menu. Once you got no coins left you cant enter the game anymore.

I hope I explained it well enough. I do have the coin pickup part but I just can't wrap my head around the rest of what I have to do. Can someone maybe link me a tutorial that implements this system or maybe help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Conceptually you just need something to track the number of coins you have. Add to that counter when you pick up a new coin - subtract from the counter when the player starts the game. If the player tries to start and the counter is zero, then don't allow them to start. Which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: I suggest you start by picking a programming language (since you've currently tagged two different ones). As UnityScript (a Javascript derivative language created for Unity) was deprecated a few years ago, I would suggest performing new development in C#. Also, please note that I removed the `[visual-studio]` tag because this question isn't about using the Visual Studio application.

Comment: So you just need a variable to store the number of coin.. You initalise that variable to the default amount. Then you do simple +1 -1 depending on action..

Comment: @Charleh Your explanation is pretty good. I'm probably going to be trying something like that. Oh and about your question. I'm struggling with the part where I need to subtract a coin whenever I click play.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a variable for the amount of coins. Call it `coins`. Also, make sure you aren’t loading new scenes, or it will erase the amount. So once the player hits play, take a coin away and start the game. Then, they can pick the coins up again. Write this in the script `coin`:

```cs
public int coins = 3;
bool pressedTheButton;
bool pickedUpCoin;

void Update(){
 if (pressedTheButton){
  coins -= 1;
  pressedTheButton = false;
 }
 if (pickedUpCoin){
  coins += 1;
  pickedUpCoin = false;
 }
}
```

You should change the variable called `pressedTheButton` when the player starts the game. Same with the `pickedUpCoin`. If you are changing scenes, then add a function to it called `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);`
Add it to a `Start(){}` function of the script.

```cs
public int coins = 3;
bool pressedTheButton;
bool pickedUpCoin;

void Start(){
 DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
void Update(){
 if (pressedTheButton){
  coins -= 1;
  pressedTheButton = false;
 }
 if (pickedUpCoin){
  coins += 1;
  pickedUpCoin = false;
 }
}
```

What this does, is doesn’t destroy the game object when you load the scene for the game. Attach the script to any game object you don’t  want to be destroyed when loading the new scene. For example you can add it to an empty game object, or something that won’t change.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I had a vacation in the meantime so pardon my absence. I was wondering; how can I make it so the variable pressedTheButton is connected to the actual physical button? I have the script but I have no idea how to connect it to the buttons and the coinscore.